# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) on AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I don't know why this isn't working. I tried this on my local browser and it works. But when I try to implement this on my live website it gives that error.

Here's my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_myposts', 'ajax_get_myposts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_myposts', 'ajax_get_myposts' );

function ajax_get_myposts() {

  $countterms = wp_count_terms( 'item_category' );
  $offset = 4;
  $number = $countterms - $offset;
  $terms = get_terms( 'item_category', array(
      'hide_empty' => true,
      'orderby'    => 'name', 
      'order'      => 'ASC',
      'offset'     => $offset,
      'number'     => $number,
  ) );

  echo '<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid home-category-row">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
  '; 

  if($terms) {

    foreach ($terms as $term ) {

      $tid = $term->term_id;
      $name = $term->name;
      $link = get_term_link( $tid );
      $item_cat_id = 'javo_item_category_' .$tid. '_featured';
      $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_option($item_cat_id), array(270,250), false );
      $alt = get_post_meta( get_option($item_cat_id), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);

      echo  '

        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="category-box">
        <div class="category-box-overlay" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"></div>
        <img src="'.$src[0].'" style="" class=" category-box-img ultb3-img-center" alt="'.$alt.'">
        <div class="category-info-box">
        <div class="category-box-title">'.$name.'</div>
        <a href="'.$link.'" class="category-box-btn ultb3-btn">View More<i class="Defaults-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div> <!--  custom-category-box -->
        </div> <!--  wpb_wrapper -->
        </div> <!-- wpb_column -->
      ';

     }

  } else {
      echo  '<div>No posts</div>';
  }

   echo '</div></div>';

 wp_die();
```

}

My Ajax Call

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    var main = {
        init: function() {
            this.myajax();
        },

        myajax: function() {
            $('button.myButton').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {
                        action: 'get_myposts'
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#allpost').append('<img id="ajax-preloader" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Preloader_10.gif">');
                    },

                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        $('button.myButton').hide();
                        $('#allpost').hide().append(result).fadeIn();
                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    },

                    complete: function() {
                        $('body').find('#ajax-preloader').remove();
                    }   

                });
            });
        }
    };

    main.init();

})(jQuery);
```

Is there any one who can suggest me something for my problem.

Comment: it was a wordpress function error but is fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You receive the response [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) 500. This indicates that a server fault occured. Your client-side javascript code shouldn't be the problem in this case.

Please check the differences between your local development environment and your live website (e.g. webserver configuration, php version, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I just found a fix. There was something wrong with using the get_term_link function.

From

```
$link = get_term_link( $tid );
```

To

```
 $term_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy );
```

That was weird since get_term_link($tid) was working in my local.